# receive undefined when clicking on a button

Tags: javascript, dom

I have the following code and when I click on a button, I want the alert to display the string in the prizes array that corresponds to the index equal to the button's number.  I currently receive "Fresh Laundry!".

```html
<button id="btn-0">Button 1!</button>
<button id="btn-1">Button 2!</button>
<button id="btn-2">Button 3!</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
  var prizes = ['A Unicorn!', 'A Hug!', 'Fresh Laundry!'];
  for (var btnNum = 0; btnNum < prizes.length - 1; btnNum++) {
    document.getElementById('btn-' + btnNum).onclick = function() {
      alert(prizes[btnNum]);
    };
  }
</script>
```

Comment: your code is suffering from closure use `let`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do JavaScript closures work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are experiencing the side-effects of `closure`.

Closures are functions which keep tracks of the functions in which they are declared. In this case, `onclick` function, is a `closure`, which is keeping track of `btnNum` variable. As `btnNum` is increasing after each iteration, `onClick` function also updates the `btnNum` inside it's implementation, and hence you see `Fresh Laundary` each time.

To fix this, you can create an IIFE (Immediately Invoked Function Expression) `(function() {} }()` and pass on the `btnNum`. This will limit the scope of the closure function, which will refer to the intended `btnNum` only.

```html
<button id="btn-0">Button 1!</button>
<button id="btn-1">Button 2!</button>
<button id="btn-2">Button 3!</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
  var prizes = ['A Unicorn!', 'A Hug!', 'Fresh Laundry!'];
  for (var btnNum = 0; btnNum < prizes.length; btnNum++) {
    (function(btnNum) {
      document.getElementById('btn-' + btnNum).onclick = function() {
        alert(prizes[btnNum]);
      };
    })(btnNum)
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Makes much more sense.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

your code has a problem relating to closures, btnNum you are using in `alert(prizes[btnNum])` has a value of 2 after the loop is finished. It would be better if you just use id of each element in event handler to get the prize from array, something like this:

```html
<button id="btn-0">Button 1!</button>
<button id="btn-1">Button 2!</button>
<button id="btn-2">Button 3!</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
  var prizes = ['A Unicorn!', 'A Hug!', 'Fresh Laundry!'];
  for (var btnNum = 0; btnNum < prizes.length; btnNum++) {
    document.getElementById('btn-' + btnNum).onclick = function() {
      var id = this.id;
      alert(prizes[id.charAt(id.length-1)]);
    };
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because when your closure is called, `btnNum` is already set to 32.

You can do something like this:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
  var prizes = ['A Unicorn!', 'A Hug!', 'Fresh Laundry!'];
  for (var btnNum = 0; btnNum < prizes.length - 1; btnNum++) {
    (function(_btnNum) {
      document.getElementById('btn-' + _btnNum).onclick = function() {
        alert(prizes[_btnNum]);
      }
    })(btnNum);
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting a value in the button:

```
<button id="btn-0">Button 1!</button>
<button id="btn-1">Button 2!</button>
<button id="btn-2">Button 3!</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
  var prizes = ['A Unicorn!', 'A Hug!', 'Fresh Laundry!'];
  for (var btnNum = 0; btnNum < prizes.length - 1; btnNum++) {
    document.getElementById('btn-' + btnNum).value = btnNum;
    document.getElementById('btn-' + btnNum).onclick = function() {
      alert(prizes[this.value]);
    };
  }
</script>
```

See for you self what method u like most

Answer (score 0):

Why not

```js
  var prizes = ['A Unicorn!', 'A Hug!', 'Fresh Laundry!'];
  function clickHandler (btnNum) {
    alert(prizes[btnNum])
  };
```

```html
<button id="btn-0" onclick="clickHandler(0)">Button 1!</button>
<button id="btn-1" onclick="clickHandler(1)">Button 2!</button>
<button id="btn-2" onclick="clickHandler(2)">Button 3!</button>
```

Sure onclick handlers in HTML are kinda terrible, but without more context behind the contrived code example, might as well.

To make it a little neater you could try

```js
var prizes = ['A Unicorn!', 'A Hug!', 'Fresh Laundry!'];
function clickHandler (event) {
  alert(prizes[this.id.replace('btn-', '')])
};
elems = document.getElementsByClassName('click-me');
for (var i=0; i<elems.length; i++) {
  elems[i].onclick = clickHandler;
}
```

```html
<button id="btn-0" class="click-me">Button 1!</button>
<button id="btn-1" class="click-me">Button 2!</button>
<button id="btn-2" class="click-me">Button 3!</button>
```